# Disabling RC4 kerberos Encryption type on Windows 2012 R2

Tags: windows, powershell, encryption

I am trying to comeup with a powershell script to disable RC4 kerberos encryption type on Windows 2012 R2 (assuming it's similar in Windows 2016 and 2019).

On Windows 2012 R2, I checked the below setting:

**Approach1:**

`Administrative Tools->Group Policy management->Edit Default Domain Policy->Computer Configuration->Policies-> Windows Settings-> Security Settings-> Local Policies-> Security Options >> "Network security: Configure encryption types allowed for Kerberos"`

to "Enabled" with only the following selected: **AES_128_HMAC_SHA1, AES256_HMAC_SHA1, Future encryption types**.

Now there is also a registry setting to do something similar:

**Approach2:**

`"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\policies\system\kerberos\parameters"`
and set the Hexadecimal value to  **7ffffff8 (2147483640)**.

**Approach3:**

Then according to this article of [Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/262177/how-to-enable-kerberos-event-logging) which says `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\Kerberos\Parameters` for setting up SupportedEncryptionTypes.

If i have to disable RC4 Encryption type which approach should i take. When i take the approach1 and change the values like select **AES_128_HMAC_SHA1** only, that doesn't seem to reflect the value in registry value specified under **Approach2** or **Approach3**.

When i follow the **Approach1** and write a shell script as shown below it doesn't seem to enable the `Network Security: Configure encryption types allowed for Kerberos` . Below is my script

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Import-Module GroupPolicy

# Define variables 
$GPOName = 'Disable-RC4-etype'
$basedn     = ( [ADSI]"LDAP://RootDSE" ).defaultNamingContext.Value

#create New GPO
$GPO = New-GPO -Name $GPOName

Set-GPPrefRegistryValue -Name $GPOName -Action Update -Context Computer `
-Key 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\policies\system\kerberos\parameters' `
-Type DWord  -ValueName 'supportedencryptiontypes' -Value 2147483640 | out-null
```

Comment: I'd _very strongly_ suggest using Group Policy to propagate Kerberos policy configuration!

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Do you know how to Set Group Policy using powershell, I have updated the question with my powershell script but it doesn't seem to work. i.e It still shows " Configure encryption types allowed for Kerberos" as Not Defined.